# Safari - Overlap Menu with Top box - company page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Not sure if the right place to report but couldn't find a place to report a bug. Notice that the menu is overlapped by the top "blue box" on the company page. See attached. Safari 11.1 [image]

Comment: cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368013/hero-header-on-about-us-page-overlaps-navigation-bar-menus

Comment: @Aaron no juicy details about the bug? ;-)

Comment: Oh it's so boring, hahah. At SO, we're building a design system https://stackoverflow.design, and that big blue thing is called a "banner" in our design system. The banner component has z-index applied a little too aggressively. We didn't realize it'd conflict in a few spots. So I nuked the z-index :) BORINGGGG hehehe

Comment: Not boring at all, @Aaron! But isn't it called "Hero"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Maybe that's just the cape and it is obscuring the hero. ;)

Comment: @Joe thanks for making me laugh so hard!